# Organize separate child Models under one namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, widget, models

I'm building an app that will allow users to create custom sites using configurable widgets (essentially just child objects of a site). Currently each widget is its own separate model so I have to access them individually through a user's site object such as `@site.headers` and `@site.galleries`.

What I would like to do is set up a way to reference these individual child objects under one namespace, Widget, so that I can just use `@site.widgets` to return a hash of all my individual child objects that belong to a site.

I've looked into something like this below, but I don't think `:class_name` accepts an array.

`has_many :widgets, :foreign_key => 'site_id', :class_name => ['Header', 'Gallery']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to define this as an association. instead, you can define your own method:

```
def widgets
  headers + galleries
end
```

but remember that the result of this method will be simple `Array`, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` - so you won't be able to call AR scope methods on this.